# Wocketsocket stopped for the reason the data is not consumed fast enough

Tags: python, api, websocket

I am using the websocket api from polygon.io. Here is the github: https://github.com/polygon-io/client-python/tree/master/examples/websocket. I am able to use it, but it disconnects very rapidly.

Here is there solution: https://polygon.io/knowledge-base/article/why-do-polygon-websocket-disconnects-happen.

Roughly what I am doing is this: https://github.com/polygon-io/client-python/blob/master/examples/websocket/stocks-ws.py.

I just place the packets into a queue using `from collections import deque` but it seems way not sufficient.

How can I fix that up?

Here is what I tried:

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

queue = []  # initialize an empty queue
lock = Lock()  # create a lock to synchronize access to the queue

def process_messages():
    while True:
        with lock:
            if len(queue) == 0:
                continue
            msgs = queue.pop(0)
        # process the messages here
        for m in msgs:
            print(m)

def handle_msg(msgs: List[WebSocketMessage]):
    with lock:
        queue.append(msgs)

# create the WebSocket client and subscribe to the desired channels
client = WebSocketClient()  
client.subscribe("A.*")

# create the thread to process messages
t = Thread(target=process_messages)
t.start()

# run the WebSocket client
client.run(handle_msg)
```

Very simple, but it is not working at all.